# SwiftUI: how to add type for JSON with 0 index array key

Tags: json, swift

I am making a API call in swift and the response of the API looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "response": {
            "data": {
                "first": "Hello",
                "second": "Hola",
                "third": "Namaste"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Now to be able to integrate it into my app I need to decode the response from the API call for which the type I am using is as below:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
  let response: Response
}
    
struct Response: Codable {
  let data: Data
}
    
struct Data: Codable {
  let first: String
  let second: String
  let third: String
}
```

Now the issue is this type is wrong because the API response is actually a array with only one element (index 0), which means the above type would work if the response from API was

```
[
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "first": "Hello",
      "second": "Hola",
      "third": "Namaste"
    }
  }
]
```

how to define index-0 data in my type?

The code I am using to make API call and decode JSON:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myurl.com")!)
let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
```

Comment: How do your decode your struct? I would asume decoding it to [APIResponse].self and getting the first element should work.

Comment: I am making API call with `URLSession` and then decoding it using `JSONDecoder().decode()`

Comment: Please add the code for decoding it in your question.

Comment: @burnsi I have added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is an array of elements:

```
let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([APIResponse].self, from: data)
```

and:

```
let element = decodedResponse.first
```

should get you going.

And never use `try?` it will obfuscate all errors.